# nasm infinite loop with rcx

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have code that takes `count` as input to take `count` number of numbers and store in array

Code:
Initializing messages

```
section .data
    msg db "Enter count"
    msgl equ $-msg
    msg1 db "Start Entering numbers"
    msg1l equ $-msg1
```

Declaring `count` and `array` and macro to take input and output

```
section .bss

count resb 1
arr resw 100;Maximum size 100 word
%macro general 4

    mov rax,%1
    mov rdi,%2
    mov rsi,%3
    mov rdx,%4
    syscall
%endmacro
```

Main Function

```
section .text

global _start

_start:
    general 1,1,msg,msgl  ;Enter a count display message
    general 0,0,count,1   ;Take count input
    general 1,1,count,1   ;Display that count
    sub byte[count],30h   ;Convert Ascii to number
    mov rcx,[count]       ;Store count to rcx
    general 1,1,msg1,msg1l   ;Display message
    mov rbx,arr            ;let rbx store starting address of arr
    again:

        general 0,0,rbx,2  ;Take number as input
        inc rbx            ;go to next address
        dec rcx            ;decrement counter
        jnz again          ;jump until counter is not zero
    ;general 1,1,msg,msgl
    general 60,0,0,0      ;Exit
```

> OUTPUT

```
Enter count2
2Start Entering numbers3
1
1
1
1
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
```

Dosen't come out of loop.
Dont know why.

Comment: `mov rcx,[count]` reads quad word (8 bytes) from memory, but you stored `count` as byte. Use `movzx ecx,byte [count]` to read only the single byte, zero-extending it into 64b `rcx` value. (use debugger to validate particular part of code, check all register values, and memory content always, even when the code "does work" when run, it's very likely it is doing something you didn't expect, or just something wasteful, often watching it in debugger will give you ideas how to improve/simplify/fix (also it will be essential to make you understand what is further wrong about your reading of array)).

Comment: Still going in infinite loop. How to use debugger in nasm ubuntu. Sorry I am a newbie

Comment: In addition to ped7g's comment _RCX_ (and _R11_) are not preserved across a _SYSCALL_ instruction . So don't expect you can rely on _RCX_ containing the value you expect afterwards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info at bottom first steps in gdb + google. (I personally use `edb`, but 1) you have to compile it yourself, 2) if you learn to use gdb well, you will profit in whole GNU world of it). (even saving `rcx` will still not fix all problems of that code, there's one more thing at least).

Comment: Thank you all. using gdb and yes rcx is not preserved.

Comment: You'll have to save the value of _RCX_ elsewhere or better yet just use a different register than _RCX_. Rather than _RCX_ you could use _R9_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `mov rcx,[count]       ;Store count to rcx`

   This loads **eight** Bytes from count. However, you reserved only **one** for count (`count resb 1`). The rest comes from the next variable arr. If there are values you'll get a totally wrong `rcx`. Change the line to

   ```
   movzx rcx, byte [count]     ;Store count to rcx
   ```
2. The [System V AMD64 ABI calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) defines `RCX` as caller saved. This applies also to `syscall`. I suggest to change the macro:

   ```
   %macro general 4
       push rcx
       mov rax,%1
       mov rdi,%2
       mov rsi,%3
       mov rdx,%4
       syscall
       pop rcx
   %endmacro
   ```
3. The system call SYS_READ (`RAX` = 0) causes the same problem you know probably from `scanf`. If you don't read all characters the input buffer (STDIN) contains garbage which will read by the next SYS_READ. If you only read one character (`general 0,0,count,1   ;Take count input`) STDIN contains in any way the LF character from the pressed ENTER key. You have to empty the STDIN buffer. If you don't want to pipe the input you can use a IOCTL function:

   ```
   flush:                  ; http://stackoverflow.com/a/23040860/3512216
       push rcx

   ;    32 bit Linux
   ;    mov eax,54          ; kernel function SYS_IOCTL
   ;    mov ebx,0           ; EBX=0: STDIN
   ;    mov ecx,0x540B      ; ECX=0x540B: TCFLSH
   ;    xor edx, edx        ; EDX=0: TCIFLUSH
   ;    int 0x80            ; sys_call

       mov eax, 16         ; kernel function SYS_IOCTL
       xor edi, edi        ; RDI=0: STDIN
       mov esi, 0x540B     ; RSI=0x540B: TCFLSH
       xor edx, edx        ; RDX=0: TCIFLUSH
       syscall             ; sys_call

       pop rcx
       ret
   ```

And this is the corrected whole bunch:

```
section .data

    msg db "Enter count "
    msgl equ $-msg
    msg1 db "Start Entering numbers",10
    msg1l equ $-msg1
    fmt: db `rax=%lu  rbx=%lu  rcx=%lu  rdx=%lu\n`,0

section .bss

    count resb 1
    dummy resb 1
    arr resw 100;Maximum size 100 word

%macro general 4
    push rcx
    mov rax,%1
    mov rdi,%2
    mov rsi,%3
    mov rdx,%4
    syscall
    pop rcx
%endmacro

section .text

flush:  ; http://stackoverflow.com/a/23040860/3512216
    push rcx

;    32 bit Linux
;    mov eax,54          ; kernel function SYS_IOCTL
;    mov ebx,0           ; EBX=0: STDIN
;    mov ecx,0x540B      ; ECX=0x540B: TCFLSH
;    xor edx, edx        ; EDX=0: TCIFLUSH
;    int 0x80            ; sys_call

    mov eax, 16         ; kernel function SYS_IOCTL
    xor edi, edi        ; RDI=0: STDIN
    mov esi, 0x540B     ; RSI=0x540B: TCFLSH
    xor edx, edx        ; RDX=0: TCIFLUSH
    syscall             ; sys_call

    pop rcx
    ret

global main
main:
    general 1,1,msg,msgl    ; Enter a count display message
    general 0,0,count,1     ; Take count input
    call flush              ; flush STDIN

    general 1,1,count,1     ; Display that count
    sub byte[count],30h     ; Convert Ascii to number
    movzx rcx, byte [count] ; Store count to rcx

    general 1,1,msg1,msg1l  ; Display message

    mov rbx,arr             ; let rbx store starting address of arr
    again:

        general 0,0,rbx,2   ; Take number as input
        call flush

        inc rbx             ; go to next address
        dec rcx             ; decrement counter
        jnz again           ; jump until counter is not zero
    ;general 1,1,msg,msgl
    general 60,0,0,0        ; Exit
```